# How can I identify unused CSS classes?

Tags: css

Our development team recently took on the task of refactoring our enormous CSS file so that it will be more manageable in the future. I came up with a small list of subtasks, one of which is:

- Remove the styles that aren't in use.

The problem is, I don't know how to identify which styles are being used. Some styles don't appear to be coded anywhere, such as those found in third party controls. A solution-wide search does not find these third party styles (like the default styles that come with Telerik controls). We appear to have overridden some of these third party styles.

Short of deleting stuff and then checking every page to make sure that it looks identical, I do not know what to do. Is there a solid method for determining when a CSS class is in use?

Comment: There's some grunt plugins that will do this... https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss for starters

Comment: That's what happens when you don't clean code as you go....

Comment: If you're at the point where you've got a huge CSS file (mine is 6,000 lines) then I'd recommend against looking for an automated tool because that may introduce bugs. For instance, what if a class is only used in a JS function that dynamically generates HTML? You're better off working manually, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other online services, for local or privately stored projects you might find [Helium.js](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css) useful.